# PPP install error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, modem, ppp

I am rather new to Linux and have been playing with the Raspberry Pi. I am trying to get a modem I have working with this Pi. I am learning here but any help on how to fix this situation would be great.

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ppp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ppp
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 316 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/354 kB of archives.
After this operation, 772 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 65955 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ppp (from .../ppp_2.4.5-5.1_armhf.deb) ...
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'wireless-reconnect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service watchdog and wireless-reconnect if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service wireless-reconnect at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service watchdog at depth 1
insserv: Stopping wireless-reconnect depends on watchdog and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ppp_2.4.5-5.1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ppp_2.4.5-5.1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is even after trying 'sudo apt-get -f install'

Comment: I can see it already says "5 not fully installed or removed." so I suggest there is already a problem before you try and install ppp. What errors do you get with apt-get -f install?

Comment: Have you tried removing wireless-reconnect and/or watchdog to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Was able to fix my issue by amending the LSB header on the warning script "wireless-reconnect" added:
    #!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vpnagentd_init
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Wireless-Reconnect
# Description: Wireless-Reconnect
### END INIT INFO